# Reformatting dates

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to reformat German dates (e.g. `13.03.2011` to `2011-03-13`).

This is my code:

```
str = "13.03.2011\n14:30\n\nHannover Scorpions\n\nDEG Metro Stars\n60\n2 - 3\n\n\n\n13.03.2011\n14:30\n\nThomas Sabo Ice Tigers\n\nKrefeld Pinguine\n60\n2 - 3\n\n\n\n"
str = str.gsub("/(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{4})/", "/$3-$2-$1/")
```

I get the same output like input. I also tried my code with and without leading and ending slashes, but I don't see a difference. Any hints?

I tried to store my regex'es in variables like `find = /(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{4})/` and `replace = /$3-$2-$1/`, so my code looked like this:

```
str = "13.03.2011\n14:30\n\nHannover Scorpions\n\nDEG Metro Stars\n60\n2 - 3\n\n\n\n13.03.2011\n14:30\n\nThomas Sabo Ice Tigers\n\nKrefeld Pinguine\n60\n2 - 3\n\n\n\n" 
find = /(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{4})/
replace = /$3-$2-$1/
str = str.gsub(find, replace)

TypeError: no implicit conversion of Regexp into String
    from (irb):4:in `gsub'
```

Any suggestions for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mistake is the regex delimiter. You do not need place the regex as string. Just place it inside a delimiter like `//`

Second mistake, you are using captured groups as `$1`. Replace those as `\\1`

```
str = str.gsub(/(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/, "\\3-\\2-\\1")
```

Also, notice I have escaped the `.` character with `\.`, because in regex `.` means `any character except \n`